# How to bash array into psql query

Tags: arrays, bash, psql

I'm trying to call a bash array into a psql query which is inside a for loop, but i can't make it to work...

This is what i have so far

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' groupids=(`psql -X -A -d files -t -c 'select id from groups where parent=127'`)

arr=${#groupids[@]}

for (( x = 0; x<arr; x++ )); do
        users=$(psql -X -A -d files -t -c "select id from groups where parent=${groupids[${x}]}")
        echo $users
done
```

The output is just blank lines.

Comment: Perform all this within SQL rather than tranfering the first query result into a Bash array. This can be done as a single SQL query with an inner join of the groups table itself.

Answer (score 2):

Is it better?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a groupids < <(psql -X -A -d files -t -c 'select id from groups where parent=127')

for gid in "${groupids[@]}"
do
    # check that we're dealing with digits
    [[ $gid =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]] || { echo "invalid format: $gid" >&2; continue; }

    users=$(psql -X -A -d files -t -c "select id from groups where parent=$gid")
    echo "$users"
done
```

Comment: Why transfer groupids into a bash array rather than performing a sql inner join from the groups table on itself?

Comment: Like this? `select id from groups g1 inner join groups g2 on g2.id = 127 and g1.parent = g2.id` but what he's doing is more like: `select id from groups where parent in ( select id from groups where parent = 127)`

Comment: Looks about right